# Tracing Pthread calls

Tags: pthreads, posix, trace

I'm interested in tracing pthread calls in linux. I have found this tool "http://nptltracetool.sourceforge.net/" but unfortunately it does not work with 64 bit architecture which I have. Does anybody know a tool or method which will do it for me?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of tools for tracing pthread calls:

- [Linux Trace Toolkit](http://lttng.org/)
- [EZTrace](http://eztrace.gforge.inria.fr/)
- VampirTrace

Answer (score 0):

I have written a small tool called [mutextrace](http://www.hogyros.de/download/mutextrace-0.1.tar.gz); this one has a focus on mutex debugging and cannot do much, but should give you a good starting point.

I also accept patches or offers to take over the package and do something sensible with it, as my time is rather limited at the moment (so I spend it on SO).